# how to parse a json mailgun sendmessage response in php?

Tags: php, json, parsing, sendmessage, mailgun

Here is my code:

```
$this->view->assign('mail', $mail);
         $mg = new Mailgun($this->getMailgunAPIKey());
         $domain = "sandbox1111.mailgun.org";  
         $res =  $mg->sendMessage($domain, array('from'    => 'bob@sandbox3445.mailgun.org', 
                            'to'      => 'mee@xxxxx.com', 
                            'subject' => $mail->getSubject(), 
                            'text'    => $mail->getBody()));
         var_dump( $res);
```

and here is what gets printed out by the var_dump:

```
object(stdClass)#228 (2) { ["http_response_body"]=> object(stdClass)#223 (2) { ["message"]=> string(18) "Queued. Thank you." ["id"]=> string(52) "<20131211155824.31559.48115@sandbox1111.mailgun.org>" } ["http_response_code"]=> int(200) }
```

I tried `var_dump( json_decode($res));` but that prints out NULL.   How do I access the ["http_response_code"] for instance?

ANSWER:

```
  var_dump( $res); 
         echo __LINE__.'<br/><br/>';
         var_dump( $res->http_response_body );
         echo __LINE__.$res->http_response_code.'<br/><br/>';
         echo $res->http_response_body->message.'<br/><br/>';
```

prints

```
object(stdClass)#228 (2) { ["http_response_body"]=> object(stdClass)#223 (2) { ["message"]=> string(18) "Queued. Thank you." ["id"]=> string(52) "<20131211161740.16663.18744@sandbox3445.mailgun.org>" } ["http_response_code"]=> int(200) } 150

object(stdClass)#223 (2) { ["message"]=> string(18) "Queued. Thank you." ["id"]=> string(52) "<20131211161740.16663.18744@sandbox3445.mailgun.org>" } 152200

Queued. Thank you.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable is already json_decoded, with the second parameter to `false`.
`json_decode()` works with objects by default (default = `false` in this case), if you want an array, use the 2nd parameter `true`, see http://php.net/json_decode.

I prefere object notation.

> How do I access the ["http_response_code"] for instance?

```
$res->http_response_body

echo $res->http_response_body->message
//prints "Queued. Thank you."
```

Comment: thanks Dan!   I had been using the second param but that way it too returned NULL.  I guess the mailgun php library already does the decoding to object.

Comment: Yep, it is, already decoded in Mailgun obviously. if you see any `stdClass` you always access members by `->`, glad to help, thanks

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of time. I ended up using `echo json_encode ($result->http_response_body);`